# How do I get the width of an overflow-ed div that's a child of a smaller div?

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I'm using Materialize and I have a a list of message thread (which are links) inside a col s12 l9 div (to set the number of columns for the div). Only 5 threads links are shown at a time, and then there is a link to load another 5 message threads (through AJAX) next to it. I use overflow: scroll, and white-space: nowrap to keep everything on a single row that users can scroll horizontally to see all the buttons.

The problem I'm having is that when a user clicks the "load more" button, I want it to scroll to the right end of the div. I use $('.topics').animate({scrollLeft: width}, 1000) to do that. But I can't get a correct number for width. $('.topics').width() returns the size as it appears on screen. Everything else I've tried (outerWidth(), getting the right position, and various vanilla js approaches) haven't worked.

Comment: You can use `$('.topics')[0].scrollWidth`. See: [.scrollWidth property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth).

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thanks a bunch.